# Deleting a layer using Get Request WFS

Tags: wfs

I'm trying to delete a layer/features in my WFS I don't quite understand how the GET request for this works. I've got this so far :

http://192.168.3.169:8080/geoserver/ows?SERVICE=WFS&VERSION=2.0.0&request=Transaction&operation=Delete&typename=NaturalEarth:ne_10m_bathymetry_A_10000

But this doesnt work. I simply want to delete a Layer from my WFS via a Get Request. Also how do I use this to delete/edit/update/insert features within a layer?

I've tried reading the docs but don't quite understand it , still new to WFS

Comment: You must identify what you want to delete. Get data: http://demo.opengeo.org/geoserver/wfs?request=getfeature&version=2.0&service=wfs&typename=topp:states&propertyname=STATE_NAME,EMPLOYED&SORTBY=EMPLOYED&count=1 see that the feature you get has `gml:id="states.29` If you want to delete Wyoming use that gml:id in your delete request. Or add a filter that is searching for `STATE_NAME isLike Wyoming´.

Comment: Yeah I get that bit, but my WFS has like 58 layers. So how does it know to delete it from states.29 from the states layer?

Comment: gml_id is unique for the whole service and thus the server should know where states.29 is coming. Not sure if it works really if there were topp:states and myns:states on the same server, though.

Comment: has transactions been authorize on wfs?

Comment: I think you may be confusing the WFS interface which deals mostly with features and the rest interface which deals with GeoServer specific objects like layers.